# PHP does not recognize CSS and stuff

Tags: php, arrays, function

**Problems**

Project1.php does not show: CSS, thumbs and sidebar navegation

I do not know what is wrong with it?

Site Structure:

```
giving
   | - - css
   | - - footer.inc.php
   | - - header.inc.php
   | - - index.php
   | - - portfolio
               | - - print
                       | - - images.inc.php
                       | - - img
                              | - - main
                                      | - - project1.jpg
                                      | - - project2.jpg 
                              | - - thumbs
                                      | - - project1.png
                                      | - - project2.png            
                       | - - project1.php
                       | - - project2.php
               | - - print.php

         | - - web
                | - - images.inc.php
                | - - img 
                ....
                | - - web.php

                | - - consulting
                | - - consulting.php

                | - - illustration
                | - - illustration.php
```

The Index.php looks like:

```
<?php    
                $page = $_GET['page'];

                if (!$page) {
                 $page = 'page';
                }          

            include("header.inc.php");
            include("portfolio/".$page.".php");
            include("footer.inc.php");
?>
```

The Thumbs linking to pages:

```
<ul id="thumbs">

  <?php
  $dir = 'portfolio/print/img/thumbs/';
  $path = 'portfolio/print/';

  $fileTypes = array( '.png', '.jpg', '.gif');

  foreach( $fileTypes as $extension ) {
      foreach( glob($dir . '*' . $extension) as $projectImage ) {
          $projectName = basename($projectImage, $extension);
          $project = $projectName . '.php';
          echo '<li>
              <a href="'. $path . $project . '">
              <img src="' . $projectImage . '" alt="' . $projectName . '" />
              <strong>'. $projectName .'</strong>
              </a>
              </li>';
      }
  }
// Thanks to Maggie for the Help!
?>
```

Project1.php:

I'm including  footer.inc.php / header.inc.php / images.inc.php like so:

```
<?php
   $path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
   $path .= "/giving/header.inc.php";
   include_once($path);
?>
<?php
   $path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
   $path .= "giving/portfolio/print/images.inc.php";
   include_once($path);
?>
<!-- Content -->
<!-- Title - Print -->  
    <p class="title">Print <span id="clients_name">Print 1</span></p>                               
    <h2 id="img">
      <?php

        $main_dir = 'img/main/';
        $scan = scandir ($main_dir);

        echo '<img src="' . $main_dir . $scan[3] . ' "alt ="images" />';
        ?>
    </h2>
    <p class="brief">
        <span>Brief:</span> He felt a slight itch up on his belly; pushed himself slowly up on his back towards the headboard so that he could lift his head better; found where the itch was, and saw that it was covered with lots of little white spots which he didn't know what to make of. 
        </p>        
    <h4><a title="Go Live" href="#">Live Project</a></h4>

<?php
   $path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
   $path .= "/giving/footer.inc.php";
   include_once($path);
?>
```

**Header.inc.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Giving - 1st theme</title>
        <link href="css/layout.css" type="text/css" media="screen, projection" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
  <div id="portfolio">
    <div class="content">
        <h1><a href="#home" title="Panel's Home Page">Panels Logo Portfolio</a></h1>
        <div id="projects_services">
            <div id="print_section">
                <?php // $currentPage = basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']); ?>
                <ul id="sidebar">


                  <?php

                        $sections = array("Print", "Web", "Illustration", "Consulting");

                        foreach ($sections as $row) { 
                            echo "<li><a href=\"index.php?page=$row\"";

                            if ($row == $page) { 

                                echo "class=\"selected\"";
                            }

                            echo ">$row</a></li>\n";                
                        }


                    ?>

              <!-- <li>
                <a href="print.php" <?php // if ($currentPage == 
                //                 'index.php?page=print.php') {echo 'class="selected"';} ?> title=" ">Print</a> 
              </li>           
              <li>
                <a href="index.php?page=web.php" <?php // if ($currentPage == 
                //                 'index.php?page=web.php') {echo 'class="selected"';} ?> title=" ">Web</a> 
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="index.php?page=illustration.php" <?php // if ($currentPage == 
                //                 'index.php?page=illustration.php') {echo 'class="selected"';} ?> title=" ">Illustration</a> 
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="index.php?page=consulting.php" <?php // if ($currentPage == 
                //                 'index.php?page=consulting.php') {echo 'class="selected"';} ?> title=" ">Consulting</a> 
              </li> -->
                </ul><!-- End sidebar-->
```

Phew!

Thank you!

Comment: Instead of all of that, it would help if you just posted the rendered HTML so we can see what's in the document `<head>`. PHP has nothing to do with CSS.

Comment: I think it does matter as I am using includes and PHP reads a lot deeper in the root than HTML does. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your header is linking to a relative URL (`css/layout.css`). Make it link to an absolute path (`/css/layout.css`).

Comment: Then you need to change the absolute path to fit your web server setup. If the application's root is `yourdomain.com/myapp/` then it needs to be `/myapp/css/layout.css`.

Answer (score 3):

```
<?php    
                $page = $_GET['page'];

                if (!$page) {
                 $page = 'page';
                }          

            include("header.inc.php");
            include("portfolio/".$page.".php");
            include("footer.inc.php");
?>
```

This is horrible, do some check of user input, if you don't want to someone view your /etc/passwd and other files.

If think the best way to localise your problem is to simple print to browser, where your script is looking to CSS file. Also you can output dirname(__ FILE__) and compare paths, maybe you will find difference.

Comment: Yes, I have heard that one before. That's why I would use 

<?php // $currentPage = basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']); ?>

Thanks!